# Why we make pyrogallol alkaline to absorb oxygen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Pyrogallol is activated by -OH groups but what is the use of making it alkaline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that makes them $\ce{\dots-O-}$, which is even better for oxidation. See, this thing is just ready to give away two electrons and become the corresponding quinone without any structural rearrangement.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain me why it shows colour after reaction with oxygen.

Comment: Well, color in organic compounds like this is mostly a feature of conjugated $\pi$-system, and the oxidation of pyrogallol, involving breaking of cycles and condensations that form new cycles, produces quite a system (see [purpurogallin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purpurogallin)).

Comment: Does this reaction yields purpurogallin or 2-pyrone?

Comment: I don't really know. Probably both, and maybe something more.